# Can a Tiff formated image be overlayed onto Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, tiff, kml

Can a TIFF formated image be overlayed onto Google Maps just as a JPEG can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIFF needs to be converted to PNG or JPEG

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers).
The sample code goes like that:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

Hope it helps